# C++: partial implementation of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Suppose I have a hierarchy of two classes:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual int next(int x) const { return x+1; }
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    virtual int prev(int x) const { return x-1; }
};
```

I want to create a `Modifier` class template that could apply to both `Base` and `Derived` and changes the behaviour of `next()` (if used with `Base`) or both next() and `prev()` (if used with `Derived`). Here is an inelegant solution with code duplication:

```
template<class BaseOrDerived> class Modifier;

template<> class Modifier<Base>: public Base {
    const Base& obj;
    const int k;
public:
    Modifier(const Base& _obj, int _k) : obj(_obj), k(_k) {}
    virtual int next(int x) const { return obj.next(x)+k; }
};

template<> class Modifier<Derived>: public Derived {
    const Derived& obj;
    const int k;
public:
    Modifier(const Derived& _obj, int _k) : obj(_obj), k(_k) {}
    virtual int next(int x) const { return obj.next(x)+k; }
    virtual int prev(int x) const { return obj.prev(x)-k; }
};
```

Now the question: how to do this better? Can I write down the first specialization `Modifier<Base>` in full (or write it in a general form without any template specialization), and then somehow "add" the method `prev()` to a specialization of the template class `Modifier<Derived>`?

I tried to do this by making `Modifier<Derived>` inherit from both `Derived` and `Modifier<Base>` and using a virtual inheritance, but this results in a rather ugly diamond inheritance diagram, with duplicated `obj` member variables of two different types, and is not really what I want: the two template specializations do not need to inherit from one another, they just need to implement the same behaviour for `next()`.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I assume that you want to inherit the modifiers? If so, you don't need to keep references to the object they modify since they are (part of) the object they modify.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You've put your finger on it there, that's the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

This all sounds a bit too tricksy for me - I would just make `k` a member of `Base` and have done with it - but if you really want to do it this way then simple template inheritance (aka static polymorphism) will do the job.

So what I have done here is structured the *Modifier* templates into a class hierarchy and done away with them inheriting from the actual classes whose behaviour they are modifying, since that is what is messing you up.  And when you do that, this is what you end up with:

```
template<class BaseOrDerived> class Modifier;

template<class BaseOrDerived> class ModifierCommon{
    friend class Modifier<Derived>;
    const BaseOrDerived& obj;
    const int k;
public:
    ModifierCommon(const BaseOrDerived& _obj, int _k) : obj(_obj), k(_k) {}
    virtual int next(int x) const { return obj.next(x)+k; }
};

template<> class Modifier<Base>: public ModifierCommon<Base> {
    using ModifierCommon<Base>::ModifierCommon;
};

template<> class Modifier<Derived>: public ModifierCommon<Derived> {
    using ModifierCommon<Derived>::ModifierCommon;
public:
    virtual int prev(int x) const { return obj.prev(x)-k; }
};
```

And that's all there is to it, best of luck.  But, as I say, personally I wouldn't do it at all, you're just over-egging the pudding.

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6Zyfl9dUzbVIbuYp)

---

Hokay, as per the comments the OP has moved the goalposts a bit so let's see what we can do.

To be able to access, for example, `Modifier<Base>` as if (more or less) it was a true `Base` object, you can add a couple of tweaks to the `ModifierCommon` template as follows:

```
template<class BaseOrDerived> class ModifierCommon{
...
public:
    // Add these
    BaseOrDerived* operator->() { return &this->obj; }
    const BaseOrDerived* operator->() const { return &this->obj; }
    operator BaseOrDerived& () const { return this->obj; }
    // End add these
...
};
```

So, after taking out a couple of `const`s, the whole thing now becomes:

```
template<class BaseOrDerived> class ModifierCommon{
    friend class Modifier<Derived>;
    BaseOrDerived& obj;
    const int k;
public:
    ModifierCommon(BaseOrDerived& _obj, int _k) : obj(_obj), k(_k) {}
    BaseOrDerived* operator->() { return &this->obj; }
    const BaseOrDerived* operator->() const { return &this->obj; }
    operator BaseOrDerived& () const { return this->obj; }
    virtual int next(int x) const { return obj.next(x)+k; }
};
```

And here's an example of how you might use it (I added a test method called `foo` to `Base` and another called `bar` to `Derived`):

```
void call_me_using_base (Base &b) { }
void call_me_using_derived (Derived &d) { }

int main()
{
    Base b;
    std::cout << b.next (100) << "\n";
    Modifier<Base> mb (b, 42);
    std::cout << mb.next (100) << "\n";
    std::cout << mb->foo (10) << "\n";
    call_me_using_base (mb);

    Derived d;
    std::cout << d.next (100) << "\n";
    std::cout << d.next (100) << "\n";
    Modifier<Derived> md (d, 84);
    std::cout << md.next (100) << "\n";
    std::cout << md.prev (100) << "\n";
    std::cout << md->bar (21) << "\n";
    call_me_using_derived (md);
}
```

[Updated demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/l09sL01MUs3IWNU6)

And no, I still wouldn't do this.  Design a proper class hierarchy like everybody else does.

Comment: thanks Paul,
I probably didn't make it clear that the Modifier<...> classes actually do need to be derived from the respective classes (Base or Derived), since they will be used in the same context as the original objects whose behaviour they modify (and there is an open-ended zoo of various modifiers, so making them part of the base class interface is not an option - of course in this example I oversimplified it, in reality they do much more than subtracting a number:).

Comment: No, you didn't, and that was a significant omission. One possible solution to that would be to define `operator->` and perhaps a user-defined conversion operator from Modifier to BaseOrDerived &. I'll flesh out my answer when I'm back at my desk. [ Edit ] done that, enjoy.